# Re-using the same InnerShadow component for multiple items in a Repeater

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've made my own Bevel-effect which is useful when porting a graphical artist's PDF to something similar in QML, as Photoshop has a Bevel-effect, which is basically two `InnerShadow`s, one left/top and another right/bottom.

It looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    id: root

    property var source: null

    property color topColor: "white"
    property color bottomColor: "black"

    property real radius: 1
    property real spread: 0.1
    property real thickness: 1

    InnerShadow {
        id: bevelTop

        cached: true

        source: root.source
        anchors.fill: parent

        radius: root.radius
        samples: root.radius * 2
        spread: root.spread

        horizontalOffset: root.thickness
        verticalOffset: root.thickness

        color: root.topColor

        visible: false
    }

    InnerShadow {
        id: bevelBottom

        cached: true

        source: bevelTop
        anchors.fill: source

        radius: root.radius
        samples: root.radius * 2
        spread: root.spread

        horizontalOffset: -root.thickness
        verticalOffset: -root.thickness

        color: root.bottomColor
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Item {
    id: containerNormal

    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangleNormal

        anchors.fill: parent

        gradient: root.normalGradient

        radius: root.radius

        visible: false
    }

    Bevel {
        id: bevelNormal

        anchors.fill: parent

        source: rectangleNormal

        topColor: "#88ffffff"
        bottomColor: "#88000000"

        opacity: 0.5
    }
}
```

... and it looks great! The only problem is - it *kills* performance, as I am using it everywhere in my application, and sometimes on 50-100 elements in a `Repeater`.

The thing is, that it's the exact same `Bevel` that's being calculated for each element, despite the `cached: true` - my application spends about 98% of the time calculating `InnerShadow`s.

So my question is, is it possible to utilize some sort of pool, where Qt only needs to calculate it once, as long as the `Component` it's being applied to has the same boundaries?

Thank you.

Comment: If possible, add a fully working example of the case in which performance get very bad (e.g. the `Repeater` case). That would help testing the issue.  You can try to give the `fast` property a go, i.e. `fast: true`. I highly doubt it could be a solution, though. You can also try to render the effect to a [`ShaderEffectSource`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html) and than apply that over the elements of the `Repeater`. Also looking at the source code and try to reimplement the effect via GLSL would be a (radical) solution.

Comment: Having a transparent PNG on top of the image is no option? You could use an Image or a BorderImage

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I have tried to do `fast: true` to no avail - it becomes too bad looking. I thought about `ShaderEffectSource` - but I still think the problem is the same if I cannot re-use the same, already rendered, graphical element.

Comment: @MarcoPiccolino No, it could be a plan B - it just sacrifices some customization, as I apply the effect to 3-4 different shapes throughout my application. (Various buttons, titles, etc).

Comment: Ok, not sure about the specific effect you are trying to achieve, but if the central area is uniform a BorderImage could work well

Comment: The `ShaderEffectSource` is create once and applied to each delegate. Fast rendering shouldn't be that ugly, I think it's an issue with the other settings.